# Wordpress & Elementor don't show all styles (Show only in customizer preview)

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, overriding, elementor

I've an issue with a customer site, this block I've created:

```
ul.auszeichnungenListe li { 
  list-style-type: none!important; 
  position: relative!important;
  padding: 0 0 3rem 3rem!important;
  max-width:400px!important;
}

ul.auszeichnungenListe li h4{ 
  padding:0!important;
  margin:0!important;
}

ul.auszeichnungenListe li:after {
  position: absolute!important;
  left: 13px!important;
  content: ''!important;
  border-left: 1.5px dashed #0094a1!important;
  margin-left: 5px!important;
  height: 100%!important;
  z-index:-1!important;
}
ul.auszeichnungenListe li:first-of-type:after {
  top: 10%!important;
}
ul.auszeichnungenListe li:last-of-type:after {
  display:none;
}

ul.auszeichnungenListe li:before {
  background: transparent url("https://www.coachii.me/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/auszeichnungen.svg") scroll 0 0 no-repeat;
  content:"";
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 8px;
 background-position: 2rem -0.4rem 0 0; 
}


<ul class="auszeichnungenListe">
<li><h4>Heading</h4>
Text</li>
<li><h4>Heading</h4>
Text</li>
<li><h4>Heading</h4>
Text</li>
 <li><h4>Heading</h4>
Text</li>
</ul>
```

don't work on this: https://www.coachii.me/ Website. When I put the code in the customizer it's work in the preview, but not on the live website.

I've already set everything to "!important", but it's still don't work. Had someone experienced the same issue and maybe someone can help me? p.s. Cache & Server Cache was also clearedenter code here.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you add this code via the "Additional CSS" function of customizer?  Kinda looks like it, because the CSS styles are inside `#wp-custom-css` block. You can't add HTML via this function.

Comment: I've add this code both ways, via Additional CSS and try to add this via child-theme CSS, unfortunately nothing worked.

Comment: Provide the page, where you added HTML markup. it's not exists on the homepage

Comment: Thanks, guys. The Problem is solved! It was a Elementor issue in one kind of a block, it just don't want display the border.